# Can I ask for a general overview of the types of patents available for a certain type of product, and the process involved?

Tags: discussion

I have several ideas in mind for commercialization -- some physical products, and some unique services not provided before.  I'd rather not discuss the particulars of the actual products and services, but I do want to find out about the patent process.  In particular, if getting patents is something I should pursue, what kinds of patents are possible to acquire, and what the overall process is.

Would a question asking about what kinds of patents are available, what those patents provide, and the general process in acquiring a patent be on-topic here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - one of our on-topic topics is "how the U.S. patent system works". A suggestion, a question like "Tell me everything about patents" would be too broad to address. We are looking for answerable questions so you might want to break your question up into smaller chunks.